# How to reload single file in chrome developer tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a complicated site that has a lot of css files and js files that load on every page.  I'm working on a single css using Chrome's developer tools.  Once the css is mostly correct in developer tools, (Element tab, Styles side bar), the css is copied to a local css file and then uploaded to the web server.  Since only a single css file has been modified it would be faster to reload a single css file instead of hard refreshing and reloading the entire site including images, js, and css, etc.

The site has an option to minify the css file and combine it with the other css files, creating one single very large css file.  That option is turned off while in development mode.  Adding a version number to the css file name isn't the trick I'm looking for.

Is it possible in Chrome Developer tools to click on a source file and refresh only that file?

Comment: Open that CSS file in a new tab and do a hard refresh there.

Comment: ... and then do a normal refresh of the site page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think it'll work for your scenario.

When I initially load an example page, you can see three CSS requests:

[image]

I want to refresh the `devsite-googler-buttons.css` file, so I find it in my DOM Tree:

[image]

(<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows / Linux opens up that search panel at the bottom of the **Elements** panel... makes it easier to find stuff in a big DOM)

Right-click, select **Edit as HTML**, and then append a random query string to the end of the link:

[image]

And in the **Network** panel, you can see that the file was re-downloaded:

[image]

See also: [Konrad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381712/1669860) provides some handy code for automating this via a [Snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets).

Comment: I don't think this still works. At least not in Chrome 80 with Blazor WebAssembly.

Answer (score 12):

It might be handy, in your situation, to automate it a bit:

```
function reloadCSS() {
  const links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

  Array.from(links)
    .filter(link => link.rel.toLowerCase() === 'stylesheet' && link.href)
    .forEach(link => {
      const url = new URL(link.href, location.href);
      url.searchParams.set('forceReload', Date.now());
      link.href = url.href;
    });
}

reloadCSS();
```

What this function does is it forces all CSS files to be reloaded by appending current time to their URLs.

You can modify it to target a specific file. You can run it from console, via DevTools '[snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets)' functionality or make it into an extension.

[image: Using reloadCSS function as a Chrome DevTools snippet]

Comment: [@wmertens](https://twitter.com/wmertens/status/892339365195767812) suggests that `link.href = link.href` is sufficient (haven't personally tried it, though)

Comment: @KayceBasques that's a nice trick but it only works once though (subsequent calls to `reloadCSS` do nothing) and doesn't work at all in FF.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Your snippet works. For me it reloaded the css files every time it ran.  Note it does cause the screen to "flicker" as all css is being reloaded.  I can dial that down to the one file I need.  +1 for a good answer and I would accept this if I could accept two answers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind refreshing the page, but don't want to re-download all resources, try the following.

- Open the css file in a new tab. (You can right click css files from the Chrome developer tools and choose "open in new tab");
- Hard-refresh this tab (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd>);
- Soft-refresh the page (<kbd>f5</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cms</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

According to me only Live editing is the only possible way what you are looking for I suppose. There is no way to refresh a single css file.